# Kafka reactor consumer high memory usage

Tags: apache-kafka, memory-management, garbage-collection, reactor

We built a Java application with Kafka reactor consumer. We tried to fetch the messages from Kafka broker as quick as possible in each consumers so setting up `fetch.max.wait.ms` as a low number like 2 or 4. We see a frequent GC due to high memory usage per consumer threads.
Once we plugin in the VisualVM and found each consumer having a high allocated Bytes / sec. We tried to stop the producer but the memory usage doesn't stop and it looks very consistent cross different consumer threads (some of the partition consumer assigned should have zero new message). Increase the `fetch.max.wait.ms` will reduce the usage but it doesn't explained a high usage when no new message from last fetch. Is that possible that Kafka consumer poll also container some historical buffer? (Reduce the VisualVM `Sampling frequency` doesn't change the result)

[image]

Comment: Did you find the reason ? Kindly put your thoughts or analysis